# How Do I Query for the Time Portion of a Timestamp in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

Right now I'm trying to check a timestamp column, and find out if the schedule I'm looking at starts at midnight. I don't want to check the date portion.

So far I've tried a few things, but they are all similar to this.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_summary
WHERE sche_START_TIME = TIME('00:00:00');
```

Comment: soo... why not `time(Sche_START_TIME) = Time('00:00:00')`?  basically get the time from both components and compare...  timezones could be fun with this however...

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: @xQbert . . . Perhaps you should put that in an answer so it can be accepted or upvoted.

Comment: I do that more than I should.  generally when I'm short on time and heading out.  I want a more well though out answer usually.

Comment: `I don't want to check the date portion.` - This isn't _quite_ true.  If you have data for every day for multiple years, you probably only want a date **range** (which may be otherwise handled separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time(Sche_START_TIME) = Time('00:00:00')
```

Convert both to time data types and compare them.

Though you need to be careful if timezones for either component could be different or if you need to account for variances in geographic location and times.

Comment: Note this will have performance issues if the table is large, because it will invalidate the use of indices (must perform a table scan).

Comment: agreed.  so what would you recommend ? a function based index?

Comment: Probably not.  I find it extremely unlikely that OP is interested in all rows for all time starting at midnight - a date range of some sort is likely (whether the original table represents such a subset, I don't know, but that seems strange).  If there is a range condition in the `WHERE` clause that sufficiently limits the initial set, then the use of a function isn't going to be a big performance hit.  Otherwise, creating a virtual table table with the desired date/time pairs to join to is a good option.